# Why is the button on my form ignoring the font size attribute?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have the following form (described with HTML and a CSS stylesheet) - http://jsfiddle.net/y9Z45/1/

There is a sign up button at the bottom whose font size I want to increase.

Here is the relevant CSS

```
.pricing-table .sign-up{
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 0 12px;
    font-size: 60 px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
.pricing-table .sign-up a{
    padding: 10px 40px 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 60 px;
    font-weight:1000;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    background: #888888;
    -o-transition: background .3s linear;
    -moz-transition: background .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s linear;
    transition: background .3s linear;
}
```

From what I can see, the font remains at some fixed size regardless of what I use in the CSS stylesheet. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `font-size: 60px;` not `font-size: 60 px;`

Comment: Not sure how I overlooked that after all this time. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, it happens ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
font-size: 60px;
```

or

```
font-size: 60px !important;
```